# Why we have redundant repository in BLoC Architecture?

Tags: bloc

In BLoC Architecture we have **Data Provider** and **Repository** , In many examples I see that

**Repository** just called **Data Provider** and it is really cumbersome to create **Repository** , Why **Repository** exists? what is purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually something that comes from Adopting Clean Architecture, where a repository is an interface which provides data which is from a source to the UI.

The sources are usually Remote & Data where Remote refers to fetching data from a remote source (this could be other apps, REST API, Websocket connect) and data which is from a local source (something akin to a database.) The idea behind having two separate classes for this is to provide adequate separation of concerns.

Imagine an App like Instagram, where the App manages both offline data and online data. It would make sense then to have the logic handled for each separately, and then use the repository which is what your viewmodel/bloc takes in to access the data. The bloc doesn't need to know where the source of data came from, it only needs the data. Repository Implementation doesn't need to know what is used to make an API call, it just needs to consume the fetched data. Similarly, the Repository Implementation doesn't need to know where the local data is fetched from, it just needs to consume it. This way every bit is abstracted adequately and changes in one class, doesn't affect other classes because everything is an Interface.

All of this helps in testing the code better since mocking and stubbing becomes easier.